# Exception thrown by type initializer for 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ByteArray'

Tags: exception, arrays, checkin

Please anyone has an idea what is causing this error while checking in files on tfs:

"The type initializer for 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ByteArray' threw an exception."

this is the stack trace from the event Viewer:

```
**TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation component or extension:
Date (UTC): 4/7/2014 5:57:14 AM
Machine: TFSSRV
Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/8080/ROOT/tfs-14-130413234339367965
Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v2.0.50727
Service Host: 61e34d8a-3995-492a-b0b1-b1ca43304366 (SABIS)
Process Details:
  Process Name: w3wp
  Process Id: 3896
  Thread Id: 4844
  Account name: INTEREDLB\eghanem
Detailed Message: TF30065: An unhandled exception occurred.
Web Request Details
    Url: tfssrv:8080/tfs/_tfs_resources/VersionControl/v1.0/upload.ashx [method: POST]
    User Agent: Team Foundation (devenv.exe, 10.0.30319.1)
    Headers: Content-Length=125836&Content-Type=multipart%2fform-data%3b+boundary%3d--------------------------8e5m2D6l5Q4h6&Accept-Language=en-US&Authorization=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%2fzg5WQsBAME%2f5oXFLmv2XYbJUNBj1fLeBfkKABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAkAPgBIAFQAVABQAC8AdABmAHMAcwByAHYALgBpAG4AdABlAHIAZQBkAGwAYgAuAHMAYQBiAGkAcwAuAG4AZQB0AAAAAAAAAAAA&Expect=100-continue&Host=tfssrv%3a8080&User-Agent=Team+Foundation+(devenv.exe%2c+10.0.30319.1)&X-TFS-Version=1.0.0.0&X-TFS-Session=f705371b-1a30-4e4a-861c-62d652add5e3&TF-Instance=f705371b-1a30-4e4a-861c-62d652add5e3
    Path: /tfs/_tfs_resources/VersionControl/v1.0/upload.ashx
    Local Request: False
    Host Address: 192.168.200.234
    User: INTEREDLB\eghanem [authentication type: NTLM]
Exception Message: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ByteArray' threw an exception. (type TypeInitializationException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ByteArray..ctor(Int32 sizeRequested)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server.UploadHandler.UploadFile(VersionControlRequestContext versionControlRequestContext, String workspaceName, String workspaceOwner, String serverItem, Byte[] hash, Stream fileStream, Int64 fileLength, Int64 compressedLength, Int64 offsetFrom, CompressionType compressionType)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server.TeamFoundationVersionControlService.UploadFile(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, String workspaceName, String workspaceOwner, String serverItem, Byte[] hash, Stream fileStream, Int64 fileLength, Int64 compressedLength, Int64 offsetFrom, CompressionType compressionType)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server.UploadHandler.Execute()
Inner Exception Details:
Exception Message: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. (type OutOfMemoryException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.BufferPool..ctor(Int32 bufferSize, Int32 initialNumberOfEntries)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ByteArray..cctor()
For more information, see Help and Support Center at**
```

Answer (score 4):

I was encountering the same issue just today.  For the sake of others that may hit this page, since it's the first hit when googling the exception.  I looked at the MS Social question [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d872c8a8-9ce1-4db1-a395-9c0d2e6bbc1e/the-type-initializer-for-microsoftteamfoundationframeworkserverbytearray-threw-an-exception?forum=tfsgeneral), but the key appears to be something in the App Tier Framework, I executed IISRESET.exe (as Administrator) on the TFS app tier server and everything started working perfectly again.

Comment: exactly, the thing is that when i restart the TFS server everything works perfect again. But it is happening frequently. we need to know to source of this bug.

Comment: Here is the stack trace from the event viewer: